# Fundamental group of a mapping cone

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

Suppose $X$ is path connected and $f: S^n \to X$. I am interested in determining what $\pi_1(C_f)$ is.

My guess is that the fundamental group is $\pi_1(X)$ since  $C_f = (S^n \times I) \sqcup X /{\sim},$ where $(s,1)\sim f(s)$ and $(s,0)\sim(s',0)$, and the fundamental group of $S^n$ is trivial.

Comment: Are you assuming $n>1$?

Comment: Yes, in the case where n=1, the mapping cone has trivial fundamental group since if we fix our basepoint on the cone, then its easy to retract any loop to the constant loop.

Comment: Watch out: if $X=S^1\vee S^1$ and $f:S^1\to X$ is inclusion into the first circle, then $\pi_1(C_f)=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Hmm...this problem for $n \ge 2$ is a homework problem so I would totally appreciate a hint.

Comment: In expressions like $$C_f = (S^n \times I) \sqcup X /{\sim},  $$ and like $$ s,1)\sim f(s) $$ the binary relation symbol should not be excluded from within the MathJax code. $\qquad$

Comment: Do you know can Kampen's theorem? Use it.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I know Kampen's theorem but do not see how to use it.

Comment: Well, review other uses you've made of the theorem for inspiration. Telling you how to use it in such a simple problem would ruin it for you, and you wanted a hint.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I've only used Van Kampen for simple computations of wedge products. We will be covering it more in depth tomorrow since my course will use Grothendieck's proof, which requires covering space theory.

Comment: This is a rather simple computation. There is no hurry. I suggest you try several possibilities for the two open sets in vK's theorem, and see what works and what doesn't.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez This problem is a homework problem due by tomorrow and is the only one I have left so I apologize if I don't seem to be giving this problem as much respect as it deserves. I've been trying to visualize this but it seems rather difficult since $C_f$ is guaranteed to be at least 3-dimensions and I'd like to imagine $X$ not being just a point.

Comment: But if this is homework, then all the more reason for you to do it!